# I want to learn programming ionic for mobile applications

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Anyone have a tutorial for programming in Ionic android? But in Indonesian. Thank you

Comment: Please use english instead of Bahasa Indonesia, "Mohon gunakan bahasa Inggris." .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUZwVIuuWuvcO908iUgpZJxH0TMmDFRLd, http://www.malasngoding.com/pengenalan-ionic-framework/

Comment: Questions seeking tutorials are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find English tutorial for Ionic, it will be better than only Indonesian.

Try the link :
[Ionic tutorial](http://mcgivery.com/100-ionic-framework-resources/)